# Using geohash for proximity searches

Tags: proximity, gis-principle, geohash

I'm looking to optimize point proximity geo searches time.

My input is lat,lng point and I'm searching on a precomputed set of locations to n nearest points.

I don't care how much time/space the building of the precomputed index of locations will take but I do care the queries will be super fast.

I'm thinking about using geohash as the search key, where I would first check if I get results for X chars of the key and then continue to trim down chars from the end of the key until I start to see results.

To my (very sparse for now) understanding of geo index techniques this approach should be able to produce the fastest results (in terms of query time) compared to all other known implementations (such as R Tree and co.)

Comment: Is there a significant difference between using a geohash and storing your lat/long in eastings/northings (for example)? Presumably with both you can change your search precision by trimming chars/digits. (This is purely a question out of curiosity - I'm unfamiliar with this topic).

Comment: Are these points stored in a database or in memory or ?

Comment: @MarcPfister this issue is 2 years old (for my use-case) but it’s always relevant for the community so I will continue the active discussion. The discussed data was indeed stored in a nosql database.

Comment: Also, I believe that from the time this question was answered MongoDB has successfully implemented geohash indexing and search, which proves this point. I haven’t yet seen a white paper of the implementation but the code is open and available to any party interested.

Comment: Ah, OK. CouchDB also had spatial indexing now, probably also using geohash.

Comment: Today (2019) there are other faster indexes to do this: [S2 Google](https://s2geometry.io) and [H3 Uber](https://uber.github.io/h3/), this last based on hexagonal grid, the faster and efficient for this kind of applications.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Absolutely you can. And it can be quite fast. (The intensive computation bits can ALSO be distributed)

There are several ways, but one way that I've been working with is in using an ordered list of **integer-based** geohashes, and finding all the nearest neighbour geohash ranges for a specific geohash resolution (the resolution approximates your `distance` criteria), and then querying those geohash ranges to get a list of nearby points. I use redis and nodejs (ie. javascript) for this. Redis is super fast and can retrieve ordered ranges very quickly, but it can't do a lot of the indexing query manipulation stuff that SQL databases can do.

The method is outlined here: https://github.com/yinqiwen/ardb/wiki/Spatial-Index

But the gist of it is (to paraphrase the link):

1. You store all your geohashed points in the best resolution you want (max usually 64bit integer if that's accessible, or in the case of javascript, 52bits) in an ordered set (ie. zset in redis). Most geohash libraries these days have geohash integer functions built in, and you'll need to use these instead of the more common base32 geohashes.
2. Based on the radius you want to search within, you need to then find a bit depth/resolution that will match your search area and this must be less than or equal to your stored geohash bit depth. The linked site has a table that correlates the bit depth of a geohash to its bounding box area in meters.
3. Then you rehash your original coordinate at this lower resolution.
4. At that lower resolution also find the 8 neighbour (n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w, nw) geohash areas. The reason why you have to do the neighbour method, is because two coordinates nearly right beside each other could have completely different geohashes, so you need to do some averaging of the area covered by the search.
5. Once you get all the neighbour geohashes at this lower resolution, add to the list your coordinate's geohash from step 3.
6. Then you need to build a **range** of geohash values to search within which cover these 9 areas. The values from step 5 are your lower range limit, and if you add 1 to each of them, you'll get your upper range limit. So you should have an array of 9 ranges, each with a lower limit and and upper geohash limit (18 geohashes in total). These geohashes are still in that lower resolution from step 2.
7. Then you convert all 18 of these geohashes to whatever bit depth/resolution you have stored all your geohashes in your database in. Generally you do this by bitshifting it to the desired bit depth.
8. Now you can do a range query for points within these 9 ranges and you'll get all points approximately within the distance of your original point. There will be no overlap so you don't need to do any intersections, just pure range queries, very fast. (ie. in redis: ZRANGEBYSCORE zsetname lowerLimit upperLimit, over the 9 ranges produced in this step)

You can further optimize (speed wise) this by:

1. Taking those 9 ranges from step 6 and finding where they lead into each other. Usually you can reduce 9 separate ranges into about 4 or 5 depending on where your coordinate is. This can reduce your query time by half.
2. Once you have your final ranges, you should hold them for reuse. The calculation of these ranges can take most of the processing time, so if your original coordinate doesn't change much but you need to make the same distance query over again, you should keep that ready instead of calculating it everytime.
3. If you're using redis, try to combine the queries into a MULTI/EXEC so it pipelines them for a bit better performance.
4. The BEST part: You can distribute steps 2-7 on clients instead of having that computation done all in one place. This greatly reduces CPU load in situations where millions of requests would be coming in.

You can further improve accuracy by using a circle distance/haversine type function on the returned results if you care much about precision.

Here's a similar technique using ordinary base32 geohashes and a SQL query instead of redis: https://github.com/davetroy/geohash-js

I don't mean to plug my own thing, but I've written a module for nodejs&redis that makes this really easy to implement. Have a look at the code if you'd like: https://github.com/arjunmehta/node-georedis

Comment: A couple of follow up Q - How do you calculate the neighbors? Is integer hashing allows trimming (base32 z-curve based does not, for ex. (7 is very far from 8 in base32 geohash). How is the method outlined in geohash-js https://github.com/davetroy/geohash-js/blob/master/matrix.txt similar? While this algorithm supposed to produces proximity geo-points geohash-js does O(1) calculation of neighbor cells only.

Comment: Wow, this was so useful. So much expertise in this response. Quite challenging task

Answer (score 9):

The question could be read in several ways.  I interpret it to mean you have a large number of points and you intend to probe them repeatedly with arbitrary points, given as coordinate pairs, and wish to obtain the n nearest points to the probe, with n fixed beforehand.  (In principle, if n will vary, you could set up a data structure for *every* possible n and select it in O(1) time with each probe: this could take a very long setup time and require a lot of RAM, but we are told to ignore such concerns.)

Build the [order-n Voronoi diagram](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Compgeometry/MyCG/CG-Applets/VoroHiOrder/hivorocli.htm) of all the points.  This partitions the plane into connected regions, each of which has the same n neighbors.  This reduces the situation to the point-in-polygon problem, which has many efficient solutions.

Using a vector data structure for the Voronoi diagram, point-in-polygon searches will take O(log(n)) time.  For practical purposes you can make this O(1) with an extremely small implicit coefficient simply by creating a raster version of the diagram.  The values of the cells in the raster are either (i) a pointer to a list of the n nearest points or (ii) an indication that this cell straddles two or more regions in the diagram.  The test for an arbitrary point at (x,y) becomes:

```
Fetch the cell value for (x,y).
If the value is a list of points, return it.
Else apply a vector point-in-polygon algorithm to (x,y).
```

To achieve O(1) performance, the raster mesh has to be sufficiently fine that relatively few probe points will fall in cells that straddle multiple Voronoi regions.  This can always be accomplished, with a potentially great expense in storage for the grids.

Answer (score 3):

I use geohashes for exactly this.  The reason I am is because I needed to implement proximity searches using a pyramid style information system.. where geohashes with an 8th level precision were the 'base' and formed new totals for geohashes of the 7th precision.. and so on and so forth.  These totals were area, types of ground cover, etc..   It was a very fancy way to do some very fancy stuff.

So 8th level geohashes would contain information like:

type: grass
acres: 1.23

and 7th, 6th.. etc.. would contain information like:

grass_types: 123
acres: 6502

This was always built up from the lowest precision.  This allowed me to do all sorts of fun statistics very quickly.  I was also able to assign a geometry reference to each geohash reference using GeoJSON.

I was able to write several functions to find the largest geohashes that make up my current viewport and then use those to find geohashes of the the second largest precision within the viewport.  This could easily be extended to indexed range queries where I would query for a minimum of '86ssaaaa' and a maximum of '86sszzzz' for whatever precision I wanted.

I'm doing this using MongoDB.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the GEORADIUS query in redis.

Push the data sharded by the best suited geohash level using the GEOADD call.

Also, have a look at this -> [ProximityHash](https://github.com/ashwin711/proximityhash).

ProximityHash generates a set of geohashes that cover a circular area, given the center coordinates and the radius. It also has an additional option to use GeoRaptor that creates the best combination of geohashes across various levels to represent the circle, starting from the highest level and iterating till the optimal blend is brewed. Result accuracy remains the same as that of the starting geohash level, but data size reduces considerably, thereby improving speed and performance.

Answer (score 3):

Updating for 2018's, and some mathematic fundations or historic-provenance of Geohash:

- the inspiration for Geohash was the [simple interlave of binary digits](https://static.dzone.com/dz1/dz-files/hbase005.jpeg), perhaps an optimization of naive algorithms that interleaved decimal digits, like [the  of *C-squares*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-squares).
- the binary interlacing resulted in a [Z-order-curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) index strategy naturally, Geohash inventor **not** started "looking for the best fractal curve"... But curiosally, this design optimization, a better fractal curve, is possible (!).

### Use S2 Geometry Library

The S2-geometry approach is is better tham Geohash because it uses the globe's spherical topology (a cube),  use optional [projection](http://s2geometry.io/devguide/s2cell_hierarchy.html#coordinate-systems) (so all cells have near same shape and near area), and because indexing with [Hilbert-curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) is better tham [Z-order-curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve):

> ... we can do better... The discontinuity as we go from top right to bottom left quad results in us having to split up some ranges that we could otherwise make contiguous. (...) we can completely eliminate any discontinuities (...)
> [blog.notdot.net/2009  on Spatial indexing with Quadtrees and Hilbert Curves](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves)

Now it is a free and efficient library,  see https://s2geometry.io

PS: there are also (good) non-official simplified versions as [NodeJS's `s2-geometry`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s2-geometry), and many "playgrounds", add-ins and demos, as [s2.sidewalklabs.com](https://s2.sidewalklabs.com/).

Answer (score -1):

If you end up wanting to explore the Geohash route more deeply, here's a more fleshed-out implementation of Geohash related functions for TSQL in which you might be interested.

- [QalGeohash-TSQL](https://github.com/qalocate/qalgeohash-tsql)

As to the debate between the performance of R-Tree Indexes versus Integer-based Geohashes, I have different experiences related to big data scenarios. The trade-off is the same as in software engineering between using index Arrays, HashTables, and Trees. Each has use cases in which they are superior to the other two. The same holds for R-Tree Indexes versus Geohash clustering.